# wpf listbox selecteditem background colour change without changing system brush

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a Listbox control that I want to remove selection highlighting from. I know the initial instinct will be to suggest overriding the system highlight brush colour but unfortunately that seems to do so for all controls, and I have an embedded combobox within the listboxitem template that I do NOT want the selected item to be transparent for.

Is there a way to change the selected item highlight colour without changing the system highlight brush?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the style directly to the ListBox

```
<ListBox  ... >
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
          <Style.Resources>
             <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Yellow"/>
          </Style.Resources>
       </Style>                
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: This no longer works. Current (messier) solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361138/changing-the-background-of-selecteditem-in-wpf-listbox/64361991#64361991