# Changing The Background Of SelectedItem In WPF ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

This question has been asked & answered on here about a dozen times, but none of the given answers seem to work.  The question: In a WPF ListBox, how do you change the highlight color (of the selected item, and/or the 'mouseover' item)?

This does not work (per [here](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2016/04/27/wpf-listbox-selecteditem-colors.aspx)) - the highlight remains as default:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListBoxSelectedItemsStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxSelectedItemsStyle}">
        <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item3</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

This also does not work (slight variation, per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994753/wpf-listbox-selecteditem-background-colour-change-without-changing-system-brush)):

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Yellow"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item3</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

This also does not work (per [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/752101/Why-is-Setting-InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey)):

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item3</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Many many answers include some variation of this (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059526/set-background-color-for-selected-items-in-a-listbox), etc) - but no matter which I use, nothing changes.  The highlight remains unaffected.

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688785/1136211

Comment: Interesting.  That's closer - I do see yellow background - but it screws up other aspects of the items (i.e. now they're centered rather than left-aligned, they don't fill up the width, etc). So it seems to be changing a lot more than just background.

Comment: Not for me.....

Comment: By default, the highlight and clickable zone goes the full width of the listbox.  With that, it only highlights right over the text itself, and you can only click right on the text, making the click zone significantly smaller & the functional behavior of the items non-standard.  That's not what it's doing for you?  I can post comparative screenshots if it's not clear...

Comment: Works fine for me, as already said. With just the ItemContainerStyle of course, not the rest of that XAML.

Comment: Here's how it looks: lnk2.tk/snaps/2020-10-14_14.24.12.png . The yellow highlight only covers the text, as does the corresponding click zone. Here's the default: lnk2.tk/snaps/2020-10-14_14.25.34.png , where the default highlight & click zone goes the full width. This isn't how it's behaving for you...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of the versions you tried amount to basically the same thing: they provide a new resource, using the same key that is used by the default `ListBoxItem` control template. In theory, by providing a new resource item with the same key, when it comes time for the framework to look for the appropriate resource, it will traverse the loaded resource dictionaries, find yours first, and use that instead of the original one used by default.

But it seems that there are a couple of problems:

- First, the key being used has changed since those references were provided. When I look at the current `ListBoxItem` style, it uses regular strings as keys, not these properties in the `SystemColors` class. The current key name is `"Item.SelectedActive.Background"` for setting the background when the item is selected and has focus.
- Secondly though, even when using the new key, I was unable to get the resource item to be found and used. The original default brush is still being used, in spite of the theory being sound.

There is probably some way to still get it to work. But figuring that out would take time, stepping through the code in the debugger and watching to see what WPF is doing when the control is initialized and when the trigger is triggered. Such an investigation would probably shed light on how WPF is looking up the resource, and how one might manage to cause your own resource with the same key to be found instead.

But at the moment, I don't have time to do all that. And I *do* know how to make it work via brute force. One of the biggest hammers in the XAML toolbox is the *"Edit Template"* command in the XAML Designer. For this particular purpose, you want to create a copy of the `ListBoxItem` template so you can use an edited version of that. Right-click on the `ListBox` in Design mode in the XAML editor and go to this menu:

[image]

Choose the "Edit a Copy…" menu item.

That will add new resources to your file that look like this:

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="#3DDADADA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
          </MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
              <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
          </MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
              <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
          </MultiTrigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

It will also update the `ListBox` in the XAML to reference that style for the item container template. At this point, you can edit the resources to your heart's content. For example, change the brush for the `"Item.SelectedActive.Background"` key:

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="Black"/>
```

Given that the WPF documentation does discuss the resource hierarchy and how resources are found by key, it does seem like it should be possible to get this to work without completely overriding the item container style like this. But I don't see a way how at the moment.

For what it's worth, the above is basically what is being proposed in [Changing WPF Listbox SelectedItem text color and highlight/background Color using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28686752), minus all the extra details found in that question. In a sense, this question could be considered a duplicate of that.

There are a couple of other questions that you might find relevant, if this is something you run into a lot and want a less messy solution. In particular, you can use markup extensions to customize how styles are handled, allowing you to merge or otherwise manipulate the resource dictionaries as they are handled at *compile* time. This is a lot more complicated approach, but might be worth it if this comes up a lot in your projects. See e.g.:
[XAML Combine Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5745001)
[How to apply multiple styles in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16096)
Your question really is *not* a duplicate of either of those, but the basic technique could be applied in your situation anyway.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks!!  How unbelievably frustrating though that apparently Microsoft took it upon themselves to completely break how this used to work, thus invalidating 99% of answers that are out there (I spent hours trying solutions, none of which worked as they were described).  This is a bit ugly, but at least it's functional.  I guess I should post some notes on some of those other questions that the answer is no longer valid...

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand how something like that could break. For that matter, I still don't really understand why it's not sufficient to still use the same technique, but with a different resource key. Assuming I haven't overlooked something silly (always possible), there's obviously something about the way the control template is being handled now, such that the resource is either retrieved earlier in the process, or from a different context. Either way, it breaks what would otherwise be a nice architectural feature in the framework. :(